# How to fix local_costmap warning on ros rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz

I'm new in ROS i installed gazebo and rviz then i installed turtlebot3. IThen i run these commands:

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch
roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation turtlebot3_navigation.launch
```

Then on the terminal output was like this:

> [ WARN] [1697980994.321218869, 4.902000000]: global_costmap: Parameter "plugins" not provided, loading pre-Hydro parameters
> [ INFO] [1697980994.343047781, 4.923000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "static_layer"
> [ INFO] [1697980994.349648280, 4.931000000]: Requesting the map...
> [ INFO] [1697980994.559158492, 5.133000000]: Resizing static layer to 384 X 384 at 0.050000 m/pix
> [ INFO] [1697980994.662667899, 5.232000000]: Received a 384 X 384 map at 0.050000 m/pix
> [ INFO] [1697980994.668890700, 5.238000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
> [ INFO] [1697980994.671354596, 5.241000000]:     Subscribed to Topics: scan
> [ INFO] [1697980994.698207561, 5.267000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
> [ WARN] [1697980994.745432817, 5.315000000]: local_costmap: Parameter "plugins" not provided, loading pre-Hydro parameters